# How to load input from textbox without using submit button? javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, barcode-scanner

im using these codes but i need to load the data typed in the textbox without pressing enter or a submit button.
this is my `aaa.php` file. im using this system for a barcode scanner :)
    
    
    
    
    ENTER BARCODE

```
</table>
</form>
<hr />
<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');
$txtbarcode=$_POST['barcode'];
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from barcode where itemcode='".$txtbarcode."'");
echo "<center><table border=1>";
echo"<tr><th>ITEM CODE:</th><th>ITEM:</th><th>QTY</th><th>SRP</th><th>MARKUP RATE</th><th>SELLING PRICE</th></tr>";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo"<tr>";
 echo "<td align= center>".$row['itemcode']."</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>".$row['item']."</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>".$row['qty']."</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>".$row['srp']."</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>".$row['markup']."</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>".$row['sp']."</td>";
 echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use Ajax and jquery. On Blur event of barcode textbox fire a ajax request

Comment: You want to Submit values ,but don't want to take any User input for Submitting ? Right?

Comment: no, i want to insert data after the user inputs. without using submit button. barcode scanning scenario :D

Answer (score 1):

Use "onchange" event on your input element for example.

`<input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode" onchange="postData(this)" />`

then you can do what ever you want via AJAX.

`function postData(my_object){`

`$barcode = my_object.value;`
`// ...`
`}`

Comment: im hoping to load the data and pass it to my php code after 2 secs. is it possible?

Comment: yep define a setTimeout() function to handle this.
checkout http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp